# Join multiline string into an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, beautifulsoup

In short, my code is supposed to take text from specific tags within a website's HTML (with the help of beautifulsoup4) then load them into an array.

I have tried various methods but been unable to join a multiline string into a single array. How would you go about this? Printing `productBrands` returns text line by line.

***Current code:***

```python
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

productData = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "detail"})

for item in productData:
    productBrands = item.contents[1].text
```

Comment: Do you want to have each line as a separate element in the array?

Comment: @JoeR Yes, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you need to gather the results of `get_text()` in a list:

```
[product.get_text(strip=True) for product in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "detail"})]
```

Note that there is a shorter way to locate the elements in this case - with a CSS selector:

```
[product.get_text(strip=True) for product in soup.select("div.detail")]
```

Comment: I feel like this is on the right track...How would this fit within my existing code. What other changes would be necessary to create the array.

Comment: @justinium what do you mean? I've posted how can you get the list of texts. Is not that you were up to?

Comment: Can you please clarify in a little more detail how the code creates a list because when I go to print, it only returns a portion of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have each line as an element in the array `productBrands`, then you can create an empty list and use `append` to add each line to the array.

```
productBrands = []
for item in productData:
    productBrands.append(item)
```